# Solving with composition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

I need help with a homework question regarding composition!

> Let A = B = C = real numbers.
>
> Let f: A -> B and g: B -> C be defined by f(a) = a-1 and g(b) = b2 [b
>   squared!]
>
> Find:
>
> i.  (f∘g)(x)
>
> ii. (f∘f)(y)

Does anybody know how to solve these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$(f∘g)(x) = f(g(x)) = g(x) - 1 = x^2 - 1$$

and

$$(f∘f)(y) = f(f(y)) = f(y) - 1 = y - 1 - 1 = y - 2$$

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!

Comment: If you want, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the V at the left of the answer.